# Safari / Bootstrap / Carousel Bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My team and I are working on a site and are hitting a strange bug on Safari.

The URL is http://huskyhealthct.org/Testing2grey/kitchenSink/index.html

Basically what is happening on the menu is that when the user hovers, the menu drops down but appears BEHIND the carousel instead of over it.

We looked at our z-indexes and didn't get too far.  I'm wondering if it has SOMETHING to do with the transition effect but, I'm not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Is it okay on firefox/chrome?

Comment: Yes it is perfect on firefox and chrome AND strangely enough internet explorer.